# the number $\sqrt{1+5^n+6^n+11^n}$ is an integer

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

How can i prove that  $\sqrt{1+5^n+6^n+11^n}$ is an integer??

**PS : i shouldn't use induction**

Comment: It doesn't work for $n=1$.  Sorry, it doesn't work for all $n \in \mathbb N$.  As of now, $\sqrt{23} \notin \mathbb Z$.

Comment: Does it even hold for $n=1$?

Comment: sorry i have to remake my question !!

Answer (score 7):

$n > 0 \Rightarrow 1+5^n+6^n+11^n \equiv 3 \mod 5,$ hence this is never an integer except when $n=0.$

Comment: can you please explain to me why did you choose mod 5 !!

Comment: @awiya I noticed the $5,$ then noticed that $11 \equiv 6 \equiv 1 \bmod 5.$

Comment: get it ... thank you @Display name